# How tightly will gzip compress a given string?

Tags: .net, compression, gzip

Given the length in characters or bytes of some array `array()`, is there any way to know what the compressed length/size of the result will be?

An example code is below.

```
    Dim c() As Byte
    Using memory As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream()
        Using gzip As System.IO.Compression.GZipStream = New System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(memory, System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Compress, True)
            gzip.Write(array, 0, array.Length)
        End Using
        c = memory.ToArray()
    End Using
```

I can run tests for example types of data (I happen to be working with all ASCII characters, a simple XML, so I am getting around 9:1 compression), but is there any way to know the compression ratio before compressing and querying?

My specific use case is a variable amount of input data in `array()`, compressed and sent via webservice, to an API that limits the size of the call. I will be able to loop through and send multiple calls, if my compressed data is too long for a single call (will probably happen about once every 10 calls), but I don't know how to tell what is too big.

I could simply make a conservative guess (maybe, I know compression will be at least 1.5:1, and so don't create an `array()` that would make a 1.5:1 compressed string bigger than this API allows), but I would prefer to be a bit more precise. This webservice also limits the number of calls/day, so just sending 100 calls/day is not ideal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to know for certain what the size will be is to actually run through the compression algorithm. If you want to do that without allocating space for the output bytes, you could make a null `Stream` implementation as the target for compression, so that the results of compression are simply thrown out, but the *number* of bytes is counted.

The type of compression that an algorithm like GZip does can vary wildly in its efficiency based on the input. Compare the compressed size of a sequence repeating the same byte N times with the compressed size of N random bytes in a row, and you'll see what I mean. That said, if your data has a characteristic form, there might very well be a *typical* compression ratio that you could use to generate an *approximate* estimate.